# Declaring classes with the same name as DataTypes that exist in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

So, I'm developing a website with React and WebPack(Don't know if that's relevant information), and in the design of the website, there is a concept of a Symbol, which may be a number or an image. I'v made a class(react component) that takes in a number, or the name of an image, and renders it.
I've descriptively called this class Symbol.
My coworker just told me(I was not aware), that there is already a datatype in JavaScript called symbol.

My question is; is it a big problem to define classes with the same name as existing datatypes? How is this with web pack, are classes namespaces somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name something the same as a "type" that already exists you are literally just rewriting it for your code.

For example if I do this:

```
let Array = function() {}
```

Now when I try to do `new Array(1, 3, 4)` I will just get my new `Array` object and not the browser defined array.

So in general it is not a good idea to overwrite general browser functions because it could lead to unintended consequences in other scripts and libraries you may be using.

Answer (score 1):

The Symbol is a new ES2015 type. While you may not want to use it in your project, it's generally a good idea NOT to overwrite ANY built-in constructors, methods or properties. Same goes with extending ones like Array or Number. It'd be best to avoid the name.